Register C# Dep Injection for generic factory
I am trying to register a factory that can emit things, and do it so that I can request the most abstract version of this with DI and then decide at registration what combinations of things will actually be used.
The code:
// The thing

public interface IThing
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class ThingA : IThing
{
    public void DoSomething() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class ThingB : IThing
{
    public void DoSomething() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

// The factory

public interface IThingFactory<TThing> where TThing : IThing
{
    TThing CreateThing();
}

public class MyThingFactory<TThing> : IThingFactory<TThing> where TThing : IThing
{
    public TThing CreateThing() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

If I register and use these as follows, it works:
Services.AddSingleton<IThingFactory<ThingA>, MyThingFactory<ThingA>>();
...
var factory = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IThingFactory<ThingA>>();
// factory is a MyThingFactory<ThingA>

What I really want to do is register things such that I can request a IThingFactory<IThing>, but for instance, the following definition fails to compile:
Services.AddSingleton<IThingFactory<IThing>, MyThingFactory<ThingA>>();

with

The type 'MyThingFactory' cannot be used as type parameter
'TImplementation' in the generic type or method
'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton<TService,
TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference
conversion from 'MyThingFactory' to 'IThingFactory'

It's not clear how to register this.

Why do you have parenthesis : MyThingFactory>()

@jdweng If you are referring to the AddSingleton calls, it's because this is a function.

If you enable covariance on the interface using the out keyword you will be able to register the service.
//                              +--- Add this
//                              |
public interface IThingFactory<out TThing> where TThing : IThing
{
    TThing CreateThing();
}

Then you can implicitly cast from IThingFactory<ThingA> to IThingFactory<IThing>, which will allow registering the type. Like so:
Services.AddSingleton<IThingFactory<IThing>, MyThingFactory<ThingA>>();


This change does compile, but results in a runtime error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'IThingFactory``1[ThingA]' has been registered.'

Did you request the service by doing Services.GetRequiredService<IThingFactory<IThing>>();

Apologies, had not spotted I had this the wrong way around in the call. This has worked perfectly, thank you. I now need to go read the msdn on the out keyword used in this context.


then decide at registration what combinations of things will actually be used.

This actually implies that you might not need a factory at all. If you define at time of registration which IThing implementation needs to be used, it means that there is only one possible implementation while the application is running. If that assumption is correct, you can do the following instead:
string type = Configuration["ThingType"];

Type thingType =
    type == nameof(ThingA) ? typeof(ThingA) :
    type == nameof(ThingB) ? typeof(ThingB) :
    type == nameof(ThingC) ? typeof(ThingC) :
    throw new ConfigurationErrorException(type + " is not a valid ThingType");

services.AddTransient(typeof(IThing), thingType);

Note that factories are more often than not overused. Please read this to check whether your use of a factory is valid.
If you decide on using the factory, consider making the abstraction non-generic. For instance:
// Non generic
public interface IThingFactory
{
    IThing CreateThing();
}

public class MyThingFactory<TThing> : IThingFactory where TThing : IThing
{
    public IThing CreateThing() => (IThing)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TThing));
}

This allows you to let the factory implementation define which IThing implementation to build, while the client can stay oblivious:
services.AddSingleton<IThingFactory, MyThingFactory<ThingA>>();

No consumers can depend on IThingFactory and they get returned new IThing instances.
